# Using SpreadsheetGear 2012 library in Dynamic CRM Online

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, spreadsheetgear

I try making a Dynamic CRM Online Plugin that use SpreadsheetGear 2012 dll to process excel file attached as a record's annotation when an update is being done.

However, after I register the plugin, I keep getting this:

> Could not load file or assembly 'SpreadsheetGear2012.Core,
>   Version=7.0.5.139, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=39c186f5904944ec'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Do I need to merge my plugin dll and this spreadsheetgear2012 first? Or is it not possible to include 3rd party library in dynamic crm online plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one dll for a plugin, but you could try using ILMerge ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630 ) to merge your plugin dll with the 3rd party dll.

Still, this will only work if the 3rd party library use code that is supported in "Dynamics CRM Sandbox mode".

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Just for your info of my progress, turns out that the 3rd party lib that I used is not supported in "Dynamics CRM Sandbox mode" , running into some trust issues and now I'm trying another approach.